# How to use an active virtualenv from an installed python aplication?

Tags: python

I have a Python project which defines an `entry_point` in its `setup.py` like so:

```
entry_points={'console_scripts': ['foo=foo.main:run']}
```

When installed globally via Pip (from PyPI) and run with `foo` the application's `sys.path` doesn't use the current working directories virtualenv environment, as expected. Is it possible to write my program in such a way that it can use packages from an active virtual environment?

Comment: Did you activate virtual environment before install?

Comment: @falsetru – The application is installed globally, I've updated the question to reflect.